# Selecting any element in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Jquery we can select any element like:

```js
$(".abcd .xyz .mno");
```

How this can be done in Javascript??

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.abcd .xyz .mno')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".abcd .xyz .mno");
```

Ref: [Locating DOM elements using selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)